# How to get both data (id ,name ) of selected item from autocomplete textview when data is fetched from server

Tags: android, json, android-arrayadapter, autocompletetextview

The problem is when I select any university I got the name set on the autocomplete textview. But I am also looking for their ids which are fetched from server in key value pair:

```
"u_id": "1","university_name": "RGPV"`
```

I want this `u_id` as well with `name`. But I am only getting this name. I need the `u-id` for further purpose.

How do I get this id as well?

Here is the code for fetching json

```
class FetchUniversitytask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void ,String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

      /*  progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ActivitySignUp.this);
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
        progressDialog.show();*/

        linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ObjectAnimator flip = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imgSpoon, "rotationY", 0f, 180f);
        flip.setDuration(800);
        flip.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        flip.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String result = WebServiceUtil.getInstance(ActivitySignUp.this).getJsonFromGetMethod(URLconstant.UNIVERSITY);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //progressDialog.dismiss();
        linearLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        if (null != result) {
            try {
                final Universitydata univHolder = new Gson().fromJson(result, Universitydata.class);
                if ( null != univHolder) {
                    //  Log.d("uninholder", "" + univHolder.toString());
                    // Toast.makeText(ActivitySignUp.this, univHolder.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Universitylist = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (University university  : univHolder.getData()) {
                        if (!university.getUniversityName().isEmpty()) {
                            Universitylist.add(university.getUniversityName());

                        }
                    }
                    if (Universitylist.size() > 0) {
                        /*  universityAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ActivitySignUp.this, R.layout.spinner_item, Universitylist);
                            universityAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_itemforchild);*/
                        sadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ActivitySignUp.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, Universitylist);
                        suuniversity.setThreshold(1);//will start working from first character
                        suuniversity.setAdapter(sadapter);//setting the adapter data into the AutoCompleteTextView
                        suuniversity.setTextColor(getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                        suuniversity.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                                Log.d("univ", String.valueOf(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i)));
                                Log.d("univ", String.valueOf(adapterView));
                                String data = (String)adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
                                int realPosition = Universitylist.indexOf(data);
                                University un = new University();
                                un.getUId();
                                u_id = String.valueOf(realPosition+1);
                                Log.d("univ_id",u_id);
                                fetchCollegeFromServerByUniversityName(u_id);
                            }
                        });                       
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(ActivitySignUp.this, "Something not right  1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(ActivitySignUp.this, "Something not right  2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(ActivitySignUp.this, "Something not right  3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

here is my json code

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "u_id": "1",
        "university_name": "RGPV"
    },
    {
        "u_id": "2",
        "university_name": "Samrat Ashok Technological Institute, Vidisha"
    },
    {
        "u_id": "3",
        "university_name": "Jabalpur Engineering College"
    },
    {
        "u_id": "4",
        "university_name": "Rewa Engineering College"
    },
    {
        "u_id": "5",
        "university_name": "University Institute of Technology, Shahdol\t"
    },
    {
        "u_id": "6",
        "university_name": "Indira Gandhi Engineering College, Sagar"
    },
    {
        "u_id": "7",
        "university_name": "Ujjain Engineering College"
    },
    {
        "u_id": "8",
        "university_name": "Shri Govindram Seksaria Institute of Technology and Science (SGSITS), Indore"
    },
    {
        "u_id": "9",
        "university_name": "University Institute of Technology, Jhabua"
    },
    {
        "u_id": "10",
        "university_name": "Madhav Institute of Technology & Science, Gwalior"
    },
    {
        "u_id": "11",
        "university_name": "University Institute of Technology, Bhopal"
    }
]

}
```

Comment: Well, you're missing some code for us to answer this completely. `getJsonFromGetMethod` and your Gson model as well as  `fetchCollegeFromServerByUniversityName`

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you only have `university.getUniversityName()` added to the adapter means that you won't be able to extract the ID.

You should make an `ArrayAdapter<University>` and implement a toString method in the University class which returns the name (and optionally the ID, if you want to see it)

```
List<University> universities = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayAdapter<University> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(ActivitySignUp.this, R.layout.universiry_dropdown_layout, universities);

suuniversity.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_itemforchild);

for (University university  : univHolder.getData()) {
    if (!university.getUniversityName().isEmpty()) {
        adapter.add(university);
    }
}
```

Comment: But when I extract both the data  then how should I get that data

Comment: Extract and getting are the same thing... If you added the whole university's object instead of only the name string, you can get all data associated with it

Comment: Can anybody  help me in making the code for taking out both the university and univ id and set that in autocomplete textview

Comment: Probably, but it will still require you to have an `ArrayAdapter<University>`. https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView ... In any case, I do not think you will be able to autocomplete both fields